# Sitecore Powershell Task is scheduled to run every minute but it's running every other 10 minutes

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I scheduled a Sitecore PowerShell Task to run a Powershell script every minute but for some reason, it's running the task every other 10 minutes. The frequency in the config file is set to 5 seconds. Do you know what needs to be configured so the Powershell Task can run every other minute?

[image: configuration settings]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because of the next configurations:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
        <scheduling>
            <!-- An agent that processes scheduled tasks embedded as items in the master database. -->
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" name="Master_Database_Agent">
                <param desc="database">master</param>
                <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
                <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
            </agent>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

from the file : **\App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Processing.config**

You need to create patch file to decrease the interval.

Comment: Thank you that resolved my issue.